# How to get result from for loop in each step?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop

i want to get result from each step in the for loop and put each result from each step in different array. . 
any one can help? this is minimal of my program.

```
for i in range(3):

    a = np.array(cos(i))

print (a)
```

Comment: But what is the problem?

Comment: You're overwriting `a` with each iteration, by the way. Could you please show a [mcve] that includes the specifics of your problem?

Comment: this is the minimal. look I want to have the result for each step in different array for example. the result for step one in array1 and step 2 in array 2 and like this. for i in range(3):
    
    a = np.array(cos(i))

Comment: @m.seydi A dynamic number of variables is almost never a good idea. You should use a list or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop you can append to your list, then access all of the values later on.

```
result_list = []

stiffness_matrix_total = np.zeros((2*nnode,2*nnode), dtype=np.float)
for i in range(nele): 
    ele_stiff_mat = np.zeros((2*nnode,2*nnode), dtype=np.float)
    a = np.array([[cos[i,0]**2,sin[i,0]*cos[i,0],-(cos[i,0]**2),-cos[i,0]*sin[i,0]],[cos[i,0]*sin[i,0],sin[i,0]**2,-cos[i,0]*sin[i,0],-(sin[i,0]**2)],[-cos[i,0]**2,-sin[i,0]*cos[i,0],cos[i,0]**2,cos[i,0]*sin[i,0]],[-cos[i,0]*sin[i,0],-(sin[i,0]**2),cos[i,0]*sin[i,0],sin[i,0]**2]])

    result_list.append(a)

print (result_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two quick ways to do so. Either by appending them to an empty list **`arr_list`** like below:

```py
n=3
arr_list=[]

for i in range(n):
    arr_list.append(np.array(cos(i)))

# Here you will have List of Arrays arr_list=[a1, a2, a3]
```

or assigning them by exec command to a named array so you will have a group of **`a1..an`** arrays at the end. However, this is only recommended if you have a very small `n`.

```py
n=3   

for i in range(n):
   exec("a%s = np.array(cos(i))" %i)

# Here you will have a1, a2, a3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_list = [[] for i in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
  array_list[i] = np.array(np.cos(i))

print (array_list)
```

The `array_list` is the list of the array you provide.